# What Type Collection Can I Access By Class Type and Return Not Found When Necessary

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, entity, c++14

I apologize for the long, probably confusing title which I will try to clear up. So here's the situation, I have a tuple of vectors of Components (custom classes). Every component has an id which corresponds to it's index in it's respective vector within the tuple. The Components belong to an Entity so I would like the entity to keep track of all the ids of the components it owns. Of course the IDs would be pointless without knowing the type of Component it belongs to so that I can pull it out of the tuple. So I would like the entity to have a collection, perhaps an `std::unordered_map`, through which I can provide a class type and get out the appropriate index, or some number (in this case `SHRT_MAX`) that tells me the entity has no such component.

This seems like it would be possible with enums and switch statements, but it also seems very unnecessary to have to traverse an every branch of switch statement to just to provide the right class for the get function of the tuple so I'm wondering if there might be better way.

I have provided a sample of my code with commented out examples of kind of what I'm looking for:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class Component {
    unsigned short id;
};

class CameraComponent : public Component {

};

class VehicleComponent : public Component {

};

class Entity {
    //This is kind of the data structure I am thinking about so far
    //std::unordered_map<ComponentType, unsigned short> components
};

class EntityManager {
private:
    //This is the tuple I am talking about
    static std::tuple<std::vector<CameraComponent>, std::vector<VehicleComponent>> components;
public:
    //This is used to make accessing the tuple more convenient
    template<class T>
    static auto& Components();

    //This is kind of function I would like to be able to use
    template<class T>
    static T& GetComponentFromEntity(Entity& e);
};

//Initialize the static tuple
std::tuple<std::vector<CameraComponent>, std::vector<VehicleComponent>> EntityManager::components;

//This is used to make accessing the tuple more convenient
template<class T>
auto& EntityManager::Components()
{
    return std::get<std::vector<T>>(components);
}

//This is kind of function I would like to be able to use
template<class T>
T& EntityManager::GetComponentFromEntity(Entity& e) {
    //unorded_map<ComponentType, unsigned short>::iterator itr;
    //itr = e.components.find(T);
    //if(itr = e.components.end())
        //return SHRT_MAX;
    //return Components<T>()[itr];
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I also want to stress that I am not married to using an unordered_map, its just the first thing that came to my mind). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be looking for [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index). It's invented for pretty much this exact purpose - to serve as a lookup key in a container, for lookups by type.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this isn't just what I might be looking for, this is exactly what I'm looking for. In fact it even seems that I am able to use `typeid(std::vector<VehicleComponent>)` which is awesome for different reasons. Thank you so much, I'll post the correct code as a reference for future seekers of knowledge

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sorry to pick your brain like this, but it works well when I use constants but when I try `e.components.insert(std::make_pair<std::type_index, unsigned short>(typeid(VehicleComponent), i))`, where `i` is an `unsigned short` parameter variable. I get a `cannot convert argument 2 from 'unsigned short' to 'unsigned short&&'` error. As per some responses to this on stack overflow I changed the insert to `e.components.insert(std::make_pair(typeid(VehicleComponent), i))` without the template but now I get a `cannot convert from 'initializer list' to '_Mypair'` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `std::make_pair<const std::type_index, unsigned short>` (note `const`). That's the correct `value_type` for `std::unordered_map<std::type_index, unsigned short>`. Or, if you don't need the return value of `insert`, this is simpler: `e.components[typeid(VehicleComponent)] = i;`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Igor Tandetkik, the answer was to use `unordered_map` with `std::type_index` in a method similar to the following:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <typeindex>
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::getchar;

class Component {
public:
    unsigned short id = SHRT_MAX;
};

class CameraComponent : public Component {
};

class VehicleComponent : public Component {
};

class Entity {
public:
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, unsigned short> components;
};

class EntityManager {
private:
    //This is the tuple I am talking about
    static std::tuple<std::vector<CameraComponent>, std::vector<VehicleComponent>> components;
public:
    //This is used to make accessing the tuple more convenient
    template<class T>
    static auto& Components();

    //This is what I want
    template<class T>
    static T* GetComponentFromEntity(Entity& e);
};
//Initialize the static tuple
std::tuple<std::vector<CameraComponent>, std::vector<VehicleComponent>> EntityManager::components;

//This is used to make accessing the tuple more convenient
template<class T>
auto& EntityManager::Components()
{
    return std::get<std::vector<T>>(components);
}

template<class T>
T* EntityManager::GetComponentFromEntity(Entity& e) {
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, unsigned short>::iterator itr;
    itr = e.components.find(typeid(T));
    if(itr == e.components.end())
        return nullptr;
    return &Components<T>()[itr->second];
}

int main() {
    Entity e;
    VehicleComponent v;
    v.id = EntityManager::Components<VehicleComponent>().size();
    EntityManager::Components<VehicleComponent>().push_back(v);
    e.components.insert(std::make_pair<std::type_index, unsigned short>(typeid(VehicleComponent), 0));
    cout << EntityManager::GetComponentFromEntity<VehicleComponent>(e)->id;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you once again Igor Tandetnik!